# Dynamic Audio <iframe> embed from Soundcloud

Tags: javascript, html, css, audio, dynamic

I'm trying to embed an  audio player from Soundcloud that I want to change dynamically from day to night.

HTML:

```
<iframe id="song" width="100%" height="20" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" allow="autoplay"></iframe>
```

JS:

```
var currentTime = new Date().getHours();
var song = document.getElementById('song');
var source = document.createElement('source');

if (6 <= currentTime && currentTime < 19) {
    source.setAttribute('src', 'https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/482221002%3Fsecret_token%3Ds-ahwqc&color=%23577c5d&inverse=false&auto_play=true&show_user=true');
    song.appendChild(source);
    song.play();
}
else {
    source.setAttribute('src', 'https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/482220933%3Fsecret_token%3Ds-dEQ64&color=%23577c5d&inverse=true&auto_play=true&show_user=true');
    song.appendChild(source);
    audio.play();
}
```

Currently, the audio player isn't showing up at all on the page. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working example with jquery. But it seems that Soundcloud blocks this example here on Stackoverflow. But it's working, here's a working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yxdguq63/1/)

```js
var hour = (new Date()).getHours(); 
var iframe = $('#iframe');
if (hour >= 24 && hour <=6) {
  iframe.attr('src','https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/482221002%3Fsecret_token%3Ds-ahwqc&color=%23577c5d&inverse=false&auto_play=true&show_user=true');   
} else {
  iframe.attr('src','https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/482220933%3Fsecret_token%3Ds-dEQ64&color=%23577c5d&inverse=true&auto_play=true&show_user=true');   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<iframe id="iframe"></iframe>
```

And here's an example with pure javascript and the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/go9vs578/)

```js
var currentTime = new Date().getHours();
var song = document.getElementById('song');

if (currentTime >= 24 && currentTime <=6) {
    song.setAttribute('src', 'https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/482221002%3Fsecret_token%3Ds-ahwqc&color=%23577c5d&inverse=false&auto_play=true&show_user=true');
}
else {
    song.setAttribute('src', 'https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/482220933%3Fsecret_token%3Ds-dEQ64&color=%23577c5d&inverse=true&auto_play=true&show_user=true');
}
```

```html
<iframe id="song" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" allow="autoplay"></iframe>
```

In your example you create an element `<source>` which makes no sense. You already got your element with `var song = document.getElementById('song');` Just take the iframe and change the `src` attribute based on the time.